# Rewrite subdomain to folder in another domain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I understand the basics of .htaccess rewriting, but the following confuses me a bit...

What I want is to rewrite a subdomain 'sub.domain.com' in a way that it looks for the files of 'seconddomain.com/folder/'. Without a simple 301 redirect, I want to keep showing the URL 'sub.domain.com'.

So 'sub.domain.com/file.html' should get the content of 'seconddomain.com/folder/file.html'.

Who can help me with the right htaccess-rules? Thanks in advance.

(I assume this can be accomplished the easiest with .htaccess rewriting, but if you have a better solution to do the same, let me know!)

---

Well this is what I tried, but it only redirects and adds an 'public_html' into the redirected URL (so the subdomain is 'mijn.pingweb.nl' and the folder to redirect is 'factuur.pingweb.nl/Klanten/':

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# handles http redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mijn\.pingweb\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://factuur.pingweb.nl/Klanten/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles http redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mijn\.pingweb\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://factuur.pingweb.nl/Klanten/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mijn\.pingweb\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://factuur.pingweb.nl/Klanten/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mijn\.pingweb\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://factuur.pingweb.nl/Klanten/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: Show what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Max I added my .htaccess, do you have a good solution?